# Set SQL CLR assembly PERMISSION_SET in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, sqlclr

Is it possible for me to have the deployment / scripts within Visual Studio generate my assembly with "PERMISSION_SET" set to "EXTERNAL_ACCESS" instead of "SAFE".  I can obviously build the project and then modify the script, but I would like to have that be a setting so I can re-build then deploy to my Development instance.

Probably something I am looking over, but I can't seem to find where I could set that build property for the assembly creation.

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If found the setting in Visual Studio.  You can go to Project Properties -> Database here you select the Database to deploy to along with the Permission level of the CLR Assembly.

--S

Answer (score 1):

When the assembly is deployed together with the SSAS project (in one solution) you can change the permission:[image: Solution explorer]

[image: Assembly properties]

Answer (score 1):

Visual studio 2015 and sql server 2014 the option in the visual studio project does not seem to work. I would suggest adding a new script to the deployment with the simple command

```
ALTER ASSEMBLY {assembly name} with PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE / SAFE / EXTERNAL_ACCESS
```

using this also means you can change the perms on a per assembly basis